# Joomla: Cross site link boxes

Tags: php, joomla

I am currently evaluating Joomla for use on the the rebuild of our corporate website.

One of the features our designs have is spaces for what we've been calling widgets.

These widgets include common ones for each page, contact us boxes, section navigation, that all seem pretty easy to implement.

The other widgets we would us to highlight specific pages within the site relevant to the one you are on, and are therefore different for each article. We've called these link widgets and these are a pretty common site on many websites.

I'm honestly at a bit of a loss as to how to do this with Joomla.

From a CMS perspective I'd like to allow users to just select which three link widgets they want when editing the article and have some way of creating the widgets within the CMS as well.

Editing the link widget would allow setting a title, a bit of text and selecting the page that it links to.

Am I going to be able to do this with Joomla, and if I can roughly how to I go about it ?

Comment: So, the frontend users should be able to select 3 widgets from a list ? I don't get the idea of 'editing the link widget'.

Answer (score 1):

### Joomla uses Modules

First off [Joomla](http://joomla.org) doesn't use widgets they use Modules, or at least that's what they call them. By default Joomla does not support editing custom modules in the front end and a simple template edit will not work since it's way more complex than that especially in the later versions.

### Joomla Component and Plugins

I plugin I used when Joomla a few years back was called [Front End Editor](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/authoring-a-content/content-submission/9838) sadly its not been updated for some time now and only supports version 1.5 which is very out of date since we have the links of 2.5 and 3+ being the standard. While I have not being able to find anything more up to date you should be able to edit the Front End Editor and make it work in later versions, since its released under a GPLv2 license you could resubmit and help others out afterwards should you want too.